# Supabase reset password for email

Tags: reactjs, supabase

Im try to reset password user for supabase in react but it says resetPasswordForEmail is undefined```

```
 const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.api.resetPasswordForEmail(email)

    if (data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

I try to run the code but it gives and error because of an undefined function I expected to send an email

Answer (score 6):

You're probably on v2, it should be:

```
supabase.auth.resetPasswordForEmail
```

Not:

```
supabase.auth.api.resetPasswordForEmail
```

For reference: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-resetpasswordforemail

Check this out as well, it has some important notes you may need to know:
https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3360#discussioncomment-3947228